# ModX: GetResource showing Child instead of resource number

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, getresource

Heres a weird ModX issue: I have the following code in my template:

```
[[!getResources? &resources=`15` &includeContent=`1` &tpl=`slider-banner`]]
```

Resource 15 has an image in it I used as the banner. This works fine on each of my pages bar one where, for whatever reason, it is showing the first child of the parent resource instead (resource no. 80)

Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure without seeing your resource tree, but you might be able to achieve this a bit more efficiently using [getResourceField](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResourceField). Just place your `slider-banner` chunk directly into your template:

```
[[$slider-banner]]
```

and in your chunk:

```
<div class="banner">
    [[getResourceField? &id=`15` &field=`bannerTV` &processTV=`1`]]
</div>
```

You should probably call your snippet cached `[[snippet]]` if the content doesn't change often.

Comment: Thanks - yeah that probably is the easiest solution - putting the chunk directly in the template